# Convert daily to weekly data and deal with holidays

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table containing daily data. From this data table I want to extract weekly data points obtained each Wednesday. If Wednesday is a holiday, i.e. not available in the data table, the next available data point should be taken.
Here a MWE:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2012-06-25","2012-06-26","2012-06-27","2012-06-28","2012-06-29","2012-07-02","2012-07-03","2012-07-05","2012-07-06","2012-07-09","2012-07-10","2012-07-11","2012-07-12","2012-07-13","2012-07-16","2012-07-17","2012-07-18","2012-07-19","2012-07-20")))
df[,weekday:=strftime(date,'%u')]
```

with output:

```
         date  weekday
 1: 2012-06-25       1
 2: 2012-06-26       2
 3: 2012-06-27       3
 4: 2012-06-28       4
 5: 2012-06-29       5
 6: 2012-07-02       1
 7: 2012-07-03       2
 8: 2012-07-05       4 #here the 4th of July was skipped
 9: 2012-07-06       5
10: 2012-07-09       1
11: 2012-07-10       2
12: 2012-07-11       3
13: 2012-07-12       4
14: 2012-07-13       5
15: 2012-07-16       1
16: 2012-07-17       2
17: 2012-07-18       3
18: 2012-07-19       4
19: 2012-07-20       5
```

My desired result, in this case would be:

```
     date  weekday
2012-06-27       3
2012-07-05       4
2012-07-11       3
2012-07-18       3
```

Is there a more efficient way of obtaining this than going week-by-week via for loop and checking whether the Wednesday data point is included in the data or not? I feel that there must be a better way, so any advice would be highly appreciated!

**Working solution (following Imo's suggestion)**:

```
df[,weekday:=wday(date)] #faster way to get weekdays, careful: numbers increased by 1 vs strftime
df[,numweek:=floor(as.numeric(date-date[1])/7+1)] #get continuous week numbers extending over end of years
df[df[,.I[which.min(abs(weekday-4.25))],by=.(numweek)]$V1] #gets result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using a join on a data.table that finds the position (using `.I`) of the closest value to 3 (that is not 2, using `which.min(abs(as.integer(weekday)-3.25))`) by week using.

```
df[df[, .I[which.min(abs(as.integer(weekday)-3.25))], by=week(date)]$V1]
         date weekday
1: 2012-06-27       3
2: 2012-07-05       4
3: 2012-07-11       3
4: 2012-07-18       3
```

Note that if your real data spans years, then you need to use `by=.(week(date), year(date))`.

---

Note also that there is a `data.table` function `wday` that will returns the integer day of the week directly. It is 1 greater than the character integer value returned by `strftime`, so an adjustment would be required if you wanted to use it directly.

From your data.table with a single variable, you'd do

```
df[, weekday := wday(date)]
df[df[, .I[which.min(abs(weekday-4.25))], by=week(date)]$V1]
         date weekday
1: 2012-06-27       4
2: 2012-07-05       5
3: 2012-07-11       4
4: 2012-07-18       4
```

Note that the dates match those above.

Comment: Thanks @Imo, this works great. The only unfortunate detail left is the method's behaviour around the end of the year (my data indeed spans several years).
Example: 2010-12-29 is a Wednesday and 2011-01-05 is a Wednesday, and both are not holidays. But since we sort by week and year there is still a started week left in 2010, so the method returns also the last day of the year, 2010-12-31. 

Is there a way to prevent this? It might be quite dangerous to just remove all last dates of each year, since some might still be wanted.

Comment: A possible work-around would be to take a difference of the dates (like  `dat[,dtDiff := diff(date)]`) after this subset. If the value is less than 5 (or so), then there is a problem. For such rows, maybe choose the one that is Wednesday ( `weekday == 3` in the original set up).